# Iptables with lan network doesn't allow curl on external domain

Tags: iptables

Let explain my problem :

I got a virtual network on my ESXi with 5 Virtual Machines :

The main virtual machine which act as a firewall
VM02 which is a web server and a db server
VM03 which is a cloud server
VM04 which is a gitlab server
VM05 which is a server where I install some node.js app

the VM02 is the main web server that redirect to other VM when it receive any http/https request based on subdomain.

EDIT :: Request to my git.domaine_name.fr redirect in lan to my VM02 apache server which is on 10.10.19.98 which use virtualHost and proxyPass to redirect to 10.10.19.100 which is my gitlab virtual machines where the gitlab listen to port 80.

The thing is that now I want to install gitlab runner on VM02 to deploy the main website of this network. However, when I register my gitlab runner to my gitlab server, I got an error :

```
ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=3FcdT7By status=couldn't execute POST against https://git.domain.fr:443/api/v4/runners: Post https://git.domain.fr:443/api/v4/runners: dial tcp ipv4_external_ip:443: getsockopt: connection refused
PANIC: Failed to register this runner. Perhaps you are having network problems
```

Seein this error, I think that I have a problem with my firewall on my firewall VM.

Indeed, a curl on my external url : https://git.domain.fr/ also return an error : connexion refused

I don't have any idea of what can be wrong :

```
iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.10.19.96/27 -o ens160 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens192 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens192 -o ens160 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.19.98:80
iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i ens160 -o ens192 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.10.19.98:443
iptables -A INPUT -i ens160 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9600 -j ACCEPT
exit 0
```

What kind of rule I am missing ?

Can it also be a problem with my main web server (apache) configuration ?

EDIT :: Some more informations

```
curl https://www.google.com/
```

works fine

```
curl https://subdomain.domain.fr/
```

whatever my subdomain, using my domain name, return port 443 : connection refused

```
curl http://10.10.19.100/
```

return a response from my gitlab, which doesn't work as the gitlab is configured to be on the dns. I did those test on both my firewall VM and my web server VM, both give the same result.

Comment: If the domain name in question is really "git.domain.fr" this is not a problem to do with IPTABLES.  That subdomain does not resolve.

Comment: Of course that's not

Comment: Its not obvious - when you state "Indeed, a curl on my external URL you are stating that it IS the URL in question.  Were I to tell you the domain name "git.host.net.nz"  (an NZ equivalent) behaved that way, I would actually be referring not only to a valid host - BUT A VALID HOST I OWN!

Comment: Some questions - What happens when you try other domains, when you do it from a browser  on another machine in your network and have you verified the domain is working from other locations?     I would also be inclined to modify the ESTABLISHED/RELATED rule so its "iptables -A FOWARD --m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT" as my gut tells me that this is a problem.

Comment: Well sorry, It's a domain I own, all my websites works fine since several months, my gitlab, my cloud and every other app I installed on my virtual machines are used every day from external network. The only problem seems to be when I try to access the domain url from the inside of the lan network. All my redirect are done according to ip adresses in local.

Comment: Not meaning I own domain.fr, just that I replaced domain name and ip in the post.

Comment: This smells a lot like it is a hairpinning problem, to solve that you can configure your default gateway correctly or set up a local DNS server that resolves all calls to your domain to the local IP addresses instead of the WAN ip address.

Comment: Yay ! Thanks for your help ! That was that, Just edited /etc/hosts as a test and it worked ! :)